# how to change clone position in the screen at specific x and y positions?

Tags: mit-scratch

I am a beginner in scratch and I am creating a simple project in which there is a sprite and I create clones of that sprite and place them in a pyramid format.

My question - Once I create a clone, how can I move that clone to specific x and y position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move each clone to a different position, it's rather easy to do this using a variable. Basically, you can change the variable by 1 every time a new clone is created, in a way giving the clone an "ID" until the next clone is created. You can then use this ID to tell each clone where to go.

For instance:

```
CREATE CLONE OF (MYSELF)  
CHANGE [CLONES] BY (1)
```

...in one script, and in another:

```
WHEN I START AS A CLONE  
IF [CLONES] = (1)  
GO TO X: Y:  
ELSE IF [CLONES] = (2)  
GO TO X: Y:
```

etc.

This allows you to put each clone in a different location. (Afterwards, if you want to move a specific one of the clones, you can use the *location* of the clone as a unique identifier.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `set x to ()` and `set y to ()` blocks to set the x and y positions for clones. If you want to set each clone to an individual position, you can create a "For this sprite only" variable (let's call it `z`). When `green flag clicked`, you can set `z` to 0, then before you create a clone, increase `z` by 1. The clone will inherit the value for `z` when it was created. You can create an array called "positions" and add the desired `x position` of the first clone, then the desired `y position` of the first clone. Then you can add the desired `x position` of the second clone, then the desired `y position` of the second clone, and so on. On the clone itself, you can `go to x: (item (((z)*(2))-(1)) of [positions]) y: item ((z)*(2)) of [positions]`. This will cause the clone to go to the desired x and y positions for it's `z`.

You can view an example here: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/391539263/

Answer (score 0):

Codes here:

```
When green flag clicked
create clone of myself

When i start as a clone
goto x: [] y: []
```

( The [ ] means where you insert number )

My scratch user: https://scratch.mit.edu/users/coco7nut/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a code:

```
when green flag clicked
create clone of myself
set x to *insert randomised value here*
set y to *insert randomised value here*
```

Note that x and y is a variable

```
when i start as a clone
go to x position: x
go to y position: y
```